# Minecraft zipped version file not there

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanted to make my own texture pack and when I went to grab my version file with the textures al that was there was the jar file which launched Minecraft and a json file

Answer (score 1):

.jar is a zip archive containing (among others) java bytecode files. Change the file extension to .zip and you can unpack it with anything that handles zip archives.